# Simple AngularJS app not working in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, routes

I have a very simple Angular application that works as expected in Firefox and Chrome, but does not work in IE.

index.html is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularFormsApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/AngularFormsApp.js"></script>
    <script src="app/EmployeeForm/efController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/EmployeeForm/efDirective.js"></script>
    <script src="app/EmployeeForm/efService.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="efController" class="container">
    <h1>Start Page</h1>
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my AngularFormsApp.js is defined like this:

```
var angularFormsApp = angular.module('angularFormsApp', ["ngRoute"]);

angularFormsApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
       .when("/home", {
          templateUrl: "app/Home.html",
          controller: "HomeController"
       })
       .when("/newEmployeeForm", {
          templateUrl: "app/EmployeeForm/efTemplate.html",
          controller: "efController"
       })
       .otherwise({
          redirectTo: "/home"
       });
});

angularFormsApp.controller("HomeController",
    function ($scope, $location) {
       $scope.addNewEmployee = function () {
          $location.path('/newEmployeeForm');
       };

    });
```

my Home.html only contains a button:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add New Employee" ng-click="addNewEmployee()" />
```

Upon starting the application up, index.html should redirect to

```
http://localhost:65294/index.html#/home
```

and I should see the "Add New Employee" button which I see in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE. When I start the application in IE, the URL displayed is

```
http://localhost:65294/index.html
```

and I do not see the button. So it seams as though the redirect does not work, but only in IE. Even if I type the correct URL in the browser's address bar, I still don't see the button.

So what's different for IE?

Comment: Try adding this: `angularFormsApp.run(['$route', function ($route) {
    }]);`  -- this will fire off the router on app start

Comment: Thank you, Tom. With that it worked even in IE.

Comment: @Eddie I'd like to recreate the issue and investigate the cause a bit further; which version(s) of Internet Explorer did you test with?

Comment: Hi Jonathan,I use IE11

Comment: I am following a course on PluralSight and I was building the example along the way, as I watch the course. It is interesting, because the sample code I downloaded from PluralSight works well even in IE11, without the line of code Tom has suggested I add. We have the exact same code. I already checked a 100 times before I posted this question.

Comment: So I am guessing there must be some setting for the project that the solution I downloaded has and I don’t. That solution was built with VS2012, I used VS2013. Personally I don’t think that would have been the cause. When I try to run the PluralSight project in my VS2013 it works. Because the course was built a while ago, it had older versions of the Boostrap and AngularJS APIs. It made no difference as I used the Package Manager Console to bring in the exact same older versions of the API as the PS project had.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I may have found the issue. I noticed that deleting the history of my browser really helps, so there may not be anything wrong with the settings. Is just that the browser presents old pages that it got in the cache.